# AWS SES Add Custom Headers to the mail

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-ses

I am trying to send email with AWS SES which,the raw email will be put in the S3, on file lambda will trigger and parse customer headers.

Example:

[image: see picture]

How can i add custom headers like
X-moto-dealerId : 4324

```
    client = boto3.client('ses')
response = client.send_email(
    Source=email_from,
    Destination={
        'ToAddresses': [email_to]
    },
    Message={
        'Subject': {
            'Data': 'string',
            'Charset': 'UTF-8'
        },
        'Body': {
            'Text': {
                'Data': generated_adf,
                'Charset': 'UTF-8'
            }
        }

    },

)
```

Comment: just a side note, avoid using images for text data if possible, rather insert text as code, this is a good practice as the images might get removed in future and future readers won't see part of the question, remember your question might help somebody else later as well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [`send_raw_email`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ses.html#SES.Client.send_raw_email) function of boto3 instead of `send_email`.

Some additional sources of information:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_SendRawEmail.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/examples-send-raw-using-sdk.html